# Java HtmlUnit web page doesn't load

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm trying to get information form this web page, but apparently it fails to load it. It returns that there are only 7 divs on this web page, but when I check the number of divs in Firefox it says that there are more than 2000 on this page. What can I do to load the page? Two ScriptExceptions are thrown

```
WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
webclient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webclient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webclient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webclient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
webclient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webclient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webclient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);

HtmlPage page1 = webclient.getPage("https://www.mybet.com/de/soccer");
webclient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30000);
System.out.println(page1.getElementsByTagName("div").size());
```

Comment: `Set.forEach` is just implemented, now there are other error, please read [Submitting JS bugs](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html)

Comment: Show us the ScriptExceptions. Or do you expect us to run your code to get more details about them?